# Auto adjusting of content in javascript

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, performance, toolbar

I have a very complex requirement to show only buttons which can be fitted to 100% width. and rest of them will be moved to a drop down. This drop down will be dynamic and contains only the div's which are extra in required space. I want this to be handled in re size event of browser. The actual working resembles to the Toolbar of IE. the images are attached. 
I am free to use any thing . Any idea how it can be acheived? I am using ASp.net and Jquery
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can u show us some code???